# Match/Rearrange 2 sets of IDS in one table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, csv

I have a csv file that has 4 ID fields (ID_1,ID_2,ID_3,ID_4).  The combination of these 4 fields is unique in the file.  The problem is that I am trying to create a wide list of all the IDs associated to any of the 4 and there are matches in other rows that have additional IDs or blanks.  I want to create a dataset that looks for matches among any of these ID fields and adds a column for each additional unique value to create a complete list of associated IDs.
The merge should remove duplication of any ID.

[image]

Comment: provide an example showing the fields with sample data filled in and the desired result

Comment: Without more info its hard to help, give us some data, but my guess is a CTE would do it for you.

Comment: ok, does the example and desired result make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is to merge items from any rows on which there is an ID match. I came up with some code to tackle this, but realized this may not be the best approach so I stopped pursuing it. As it stands, it assumes the ID rows begin in the upper left of the sheet, and the code merely colors in red those ID's which are repeated. I've placed `.select` statements throughout the code so you can step through it and see how it works.

But if you wanted to continue you could add code to merge the rows at the point where those cells are colored red. If you do, remove all the `.select` statements.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub repeatedIDs()
Dim r As Range, cell As Range, remainingRows As Range
Dim lastRow As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
Set r = Range("A2")
Set r = Range(r, r.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3))
r.Select
Set lastRow = r.Rows(r.Rows.Count)
lastRow.Select
For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count - 1
  Set remainingRows = Range(r(i + 1, 1), r(r.Rows.Count, 4))
  remainingRows.Select
  For j = 1 To 4
    For Each cell In remainingRows
      cell.Select
      If cell = r(i, j) And cell <> "" And r(i, j) <> "" Then

        '*****   color cells with same ID red  *****
        cell.Font.Color = vbRed
        r(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed

      End If
    Next cell
  Next j
Next i
End Sub
```